# List, virtual e Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, coleção

Em todos os exemplos que tenho encontrado sobre entity framework, sempre usam `ICollection` para coleções de objetos.

```
public partial class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        this.Teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    }

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teacher
{
    public Teacher()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StandardId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TeacherType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}
```

Perguntas:

1 Não é possível trabalhar diretamente com o tipo concreto, como List?

```
public partial class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
```

2 Li também que EF não trabalha com coleções de tipos primitivos. O que fazer nesse caso?

3 Porque a propriedade precisa ser virtual, o EF faz alguma modificação na mesma?

Comment: O quer dizer com tipos primitivos? Pode citar a fonte?

Comment: Eu acredito que ele quer gravar um array string na base de dados, se eu.não me engano no entity core 1 estão implementando

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework), [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) utilizado em arquitetura .NET.

*Respondendo:*

**1)** Sim, você pode utilizar sem problemas o Tipo Concreto [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) ele vai funcionar igualzinho os tipos [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173156.aspx).

*Vantagem nesse aspecto é que no construtor eu não preciso inicializar essa Lista, como é feito com as interfaces ([HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), só lembrando que ele inicia somente as interfaces `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`, `ISerializable`, `IDeserializationCallback`, `ISet<T>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`) Se for tipado com `IList` terá que dar um `new List` com o seu tipo*

---

**2)** Não, realmente não funciona, porque ele não consegue determinar o tamanho de itens na lista, isso tem que ser dinâmico então as estruturas propostas são [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), ou [ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx), ou [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) e/ou [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Para manter um padrão utilize sempre [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

**3)** Precisa ser [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx), porque o [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) reescreve esse item, então esse modificador tem essa funcionalidade utilizada pelo ORM [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework). Ele vai transformar campos em métodos como descrito nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542879).

***Exemplo:***

```
//Campos
[ForeignKey("UfId")]
public virtual ICollection<Cidades> Cidades { get; set; }
```

*Ficaria internamente assim:*

```
//Metodos
public ICollection<Cidades> get_Cidades()
{
    return _cidades;
}

public void set_Cidades(Cidades value)
{
    _cidades = value;
}

private Cidades _cidades;
```

O [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) então, cria um proxy ou navegação de propriedades sobre os relacionamentos entre as entidades relacionadas. Sem o modificador [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) ele não consegue esse efeito de relacionamentos e carregamentos atrasados.

***Referencias:***

[Why use 'virtual' for class properties in Entity Framework model definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8542879)

[Making a property virtual to cause EF to load the property](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26485)

Comment: Não entendi a resposta da 2), Supondo que eu tenha uma propriedade `public virtual List<string> names;`
Segundo eu li, EF não trabalha dessa forma. Então como deveria ficar nesse caso?

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva O entity não aceita tipos primitivos para gerar informações em lista o seu exemplo não funciona também porque a List tem que ser de um classe que faça relação com a outra classe. Ele não usa tipos primitivos porque ele determina tamanho e o Entity precisa que esse dados seja dinâmico para as operações de adicionar e ou remover.

Comment: @matheus você queria guardar.um array dentro da base de dados?

Comment: Exatamente, tenho uma classe que uma de suas propriedades é uma lista de strings, mais especificamente nomes de pessoas.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva isso ainda não funciona na versão 6, eu ouvi dizer que no core 1 do Entity Framework vai funcionar gravar dados no formato json, ai você consegue fazer isso ...!

Comment: puts, nesse caso então terei que criar uma classe com dois atributos, `Id` e `Nome`, e criar uma lista desse tipo recém criado. Assim na hora que o banco for gerado será criado duas tabelas e um relacionamento N:1

Comment: Sim nesse modelo mesmo