# Erro ao utilizar Code First From Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando usar o Entity Framework com um banco SQLServer que criei por fora do Visual Studio. O problema é que quando eu adiciono o ADO.NET Entity data Model no projeto para fazer a relação, ele está deixando de criar uma das classes para referenciar com a tabela no banco.

Meu banco tem essas tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de escolher o ADO.NET Entity data Model, escolho a opção Code First From Database e seleciono para importar todas tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém a tabela ProdutoVenda não é importada junto das outras. Ela só é importada se eu selecionar apenas ela. O que pode está acontecendo?

Comment: A classe modelo é o meu contexto, devo deixar ele com o nome da classe que quero importar do banco? Não entendi

Comment: @Vanderson,se entendi sua questão... realmente não será criada a entidade ProdutoVenda, pois, se trata de um Relacionamento N para N ou seja, a Entidade Produto possui uma Coleção de Vendas e a entidade Venda possui uma Coleção de Produtos, isto é uma convenção do EF, portanto está correto.

Comment: Pessoal realmente é um relacionamento de N para N. Eu pensei que o Entity iria criar a entidade ProdutoVenda, pois quando eu vou criar uma tabela pelo entity eu tenho que criar a classe ProdutoVenda no visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Se sua entidade de relacionamento possuir apenas as referências às tabelas primárias, então o EF somente a tratará como uma coleção:

Vale destacar que as propriedades são virtuais (`virtual`), ou seja, o EF as mapeiam como [propriedade de navegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52908/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-propriedade-virtual-ou-n%C3%A3o-no-ef) *(leitura recomendada)*.

No caso, a propriedade de navegação apenas sinaliza ao EF que um registro relacionado pode ser encontrado na entidade indicada. Nos exemplos abaixo foi indicado que um Produto pode (ou não) estar associado a várias VENDA ou uma Venda pode (ou não) ter vários PRODUTO.

**Produto**
Veja neste modelo que existe uma coleção de VENDA.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Produto")]
public partial class Produto
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Produto()
    {
        Venda = new HashSet<Venda>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int idProduto { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string descricao { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Venda> Venda { get; set; }
}
```

**Venda**
E neste modelo, uma coleção de PRODUTO.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Venda")]
public partial class Venda
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Venda()
    {
        Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int idVenda { get; set; }

    public DateTime? referencia { get; set; }

    public int? qtd { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }
}
```

### Para criar o modelo - Uma justificativa

Se você observar, não tem razão para o EF criar um modelo já que todos os campos serão automaticamente preenchidos quando você vincular um produto a venda ou vice-versa.

Se ao acaso, sua tabela VendaProduto possuir outros campos (além dos campos estrangeiros), o EF irá criar um modelo para ela, para que você possa desenhar sua aplicação e fornecer ao usuário um meio de preencher estes campos.

Observe que simplesmente criei o campo Desconto e o modelo foi criado:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("ProdutoVenda")]
public partial class ProdutoVenda
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int idProduto { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int idVenda { get; set; }

    public double? desconto { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

    public virtual Venda Venda { get; set; }
}
```

**Outras leituras**
[Relacionamento Muitos Para Muitos Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6)
[List, virtual e Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130695/list-virtual-e-entity-framework)